# How to make one instance only of class template static member in case of several shared libraries?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries

I have a template class with a static member, for simplicity:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    static inline int x = 1;
};
```

But if I include the header with `struct A` definition in several shared-libraries, each of them will have its own instance of `A<T>::x`. And I would like to have the instance of `A<T>::x` (for some fixed list of `T`-types) only in some one shared library, and all other libraries accessing it.

In Visual Studio I can do it by writing in the header

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   ifdef MY_LIB_EXPORT
#       define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#       define MY_LIB_API
#endif

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    MY_LIB_API static int x;
};
```

and in a .cpp-file from the selected dynamic library:

```
template<> int A<SpecificType1>::x = 0;
template<> int A<SpecificType2>::x = 0;
…
```

But unfortunately, this way does not work with linux/clang, where in other .cpp-files I get:

```
error: instantiation of variable 'A<SpecificType1>::x' required here, but no definition is available
```

Is there a universal way for solving my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GCC you can use:

```cpp
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

I've tested it using CMake with the following setup *mylib.h*:

```cpp
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

template<typename T>
struct A
{
  EXPORT static int x;
};
```

*mylib.cpp*

```cpp
#include "mylib.h"

template<> int A<int>::x = 1;
template<> int A<bool>::x = false;
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
std::cout << "A<int>: " << A<int>::x << std::endl;
std::cout << "A<bool>: " << A<bool>::x << std::endl;
```

with output:

```
A<int>: 1
A<bool>: 0
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
# Change the default to hidden, then you need to explicitly set it
# Thus, normally, you shouldn't have the problem
add_compile_options(-fvisibility=hidden) # only for testing the EXPORT define

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp)
add_executable(example main.cpp main2.cpp) # Main2 also used mylib
target_link_libraries(example mylib)
```

Thus, for a universal option I will propose to add this define to your if else define macro list.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But in ```clang``` I get a warning from your program ```warning: instantiation of variable 'A<int>::x' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template] std::cout << "A<int>: " << A<int>::x << std::endl;``` Please help, what is wrong?

Comment: I've tested [this example](https://gist.github.com/cppengineer/83b1f59082205ad7a582dda3d59d67d5) with GNU, CLANG and MSVC. It works with all three. If you want use CMake, then CMake can automatically create the correct EXPORT define using [GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/GenerateExportHeader.html). That is a Universal cross-compiler/platform solution. I also showed this in the new example added as a gist.

Comment: To suppress ```clang``` warning, one has to add in *mylib.h*: ```template<> int A<int>::x;``` and ```template<> int A<bool>::x;```, which are explicit instantiation declarations.